# Error "The first module you upload to a new application must be the 'default' module"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I'm trying to get a multi-module application functioning for Google App Engine.  I'm developing it from this [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java).

I was able to get my application running successfully in the development server but I encountered the following error when I tried to upload to Google App Engine with the command `mvn appengine:update`:

```
Error Details:
Nov 05, 2014 11:58:15 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
INFO: Built File: /guestbook.jsp


com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?module=nbsocialmetrics-frontend&app_id=nbsocialmetrics&version=1&
400 Bad Request
The first module you upload to a new application must be the 'default' module.  Please upload a version of the 'default' module before uploading a version for the 'nbsocialmetrics-frontend' module. See the documentation for more information. Python: (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Uploading%20modules) Java: (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Uploading%20modules)

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?module=nbsocialmetrics-frontend&app_id=nbsocialmetrics&version=1&
400 Bad Request
The first module you upload to a new application must be the 'default' module.  Please upload a version of the 'default' module before uploading a version for the 'nbsocialmetrics-frontend' module. See the documentation for more information. Python: (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Uploading%20modules) Java: (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Uploading%20modules)

Please see the logs [/var/folders/dp/v_lw6kqx16bf7743hs5t9phc0000gn/T/appcfg4483555174170807292.log] for further information.
```

Other than modifying the module names, my setup is pretty much the same as the [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Google Documentation there is supposed to be at least one default module:

> The default module
>
> Every application must have a single default module. To define the default module, include the setting default in the module's appengine-web.xml file, or leave the setting out.
>
> Also be sure to list the default module as the first module in the EAR directory's META-INF/application.xml file, as shown in the example below.
> source: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/

However, both modules have an `<application>` tag in their appengine-web.xml file.

The solution I found to work is to remove the  tag from one of the appengine-web.xml files.

Answer (score 13):

Try simply removing the following line from `app.yaml`:

```
service: my-service
```

And run `gcloud app deploy` again.

Comment: Or change it to `service: default`